# relative search in lucene (not geo-sptial search)

Tags: lucene, css-position

I am having only "Europe" being indexed along with some related data,but when someone searches using the word "Germany" although there is nothing specifically indexed for Germany but logically I can provide results under Europe than providing nothing at all,is there any way to do this? Does lunene have any supporting libraries which can do this?
But I dont want to have any geo-sptial search so how can we achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that would just work out of the box by using a multi-valued field. You can have an indexed field which contains geo information (let's call it "place") such as Munich, Bavaria, Germany, Europe, World or Nice, French Riviera, France, Europe, World. Then, if you are looking for something in Bavaria, just run the query:

```
+text:something +place:(Bavaria Germany Europe World)
```

This will make all documents which have "something" in their text field appear in the result set, and boost documents depending on how far they are from Bavaria.

Comment: yes you are right but is there any other way or lib that will help us when the country Germany or something is not indexed. As practicallly germany comes under europe, I should be able to get related results?